# How to center details marker?

Tags: html, css

I have two lines of text in `<summary>` element in `<details>` and I would like to align indent of both lines and center marker. I was trying some css styles but it doesn't work. Is there any way to achievie it?

[image: my example]

I was trying to nest `<div>` in `<summary>`:

```css
.inline{
   display:inline;
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary class="inline">
    <div class="inline">
 TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
 TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
    </div>
 </summary>
 INTERIOR
</details>
```

but nothing has changed.

This changed position of marker, but it was still in range of first line.

```
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you tried, _always_. [mre]

Comment: I'm not sure the marker is selectable with CSS as it's not in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just create working code snippet for you. I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
summary {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker { 
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
 TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
 TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST
 </summary>
 INTERIOR
</details>
```

Comment: doesn't work on Firefox

Comment: in Chrome it works, thanks!

Comment: Does not work in Safari either.

Comment: It doesn't work any more. `display: flex` removes marker..